# Rails 3 :: config/initializers separate directory per environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What would be the best way to separate out initializers in a separate subdirectory per environment in Rails 3+?

I heard that all subdirectories of config/initializers will be picked up, so a subdirectory per environment there wouldn't work unless creatively monkey patched.

Example: config/.../initializers/<environment>/*.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
# config/application.rb

module MyProject
  class Application < Rails::Application

  # modifies initializers to load as follows:
  #
  # 1. config/initializers/*.rb
  # 2. config/initializers/environments/#{Rails.env}/**/*.rb
  #
  unless config.paths['config/initializers_environment']
    old_initializers_dir = config.paths['config/initializers']
    config.paths['config/initializers'] = Dir[File.join(old_initializers_dir, '*.rb')]
    config.paths['config/initializers_environment'] = Dir[File.join(old_initializers_dir, 'environments', Rails.env, '**', '*.rb')]
    initializer :load_per_environment_initializers do
      config.paths['config/initializers_environment'].to_a.sort.each do |initializer|
        load(initializer)
      end
    end
  end

  # ...
```

https://gist.github.com/1338248

Comment: Untested.  May break and injure small children.

Comment: This doeesn't quite work yet. The original load_config_initializers still looks at the original paths.config.initializers.  This may require overiding load_config_initializers and replacing it in the initializer "list."

Comment: Also I screwed up because I did not require what in rails this modifies.

Comment: This is best for initializers which differ *per environment* but shouldn't need to be changed in production.  The goal is that an app normally should NOT need code changed to change common settings. http://www.12factor.net/

Answer (score 2):

This answer avoids complexity of getting a Rails::Engine working and is credited to Bosco of [SF Ruby on Rails](http://www.sfruby.info/) meetup and friends. It also permits overriding via the command-line / shell setup and works with Heroku.

0) Change config/initializers/**/*.rb that look this:

```
FB_SECRET_KEY = 'kjkjdsfkjalsfyoursecretherelkjsdfljkasdfljdjlf'
```

To:

```
FB_SECRET_KEY = ENV['APPNAME_FB_SECRET_KEY']
```

1) I created a config/secrets.rb which is in .gitignore like this:

```
ENV['APPNAME_FB_SECRET_KEY'] ||= 'kjkjdsfkjalsfyoursecretherelkjsdfljkasdfljdjlf'

. . .
```

2) Added this line to start of scripts/rails:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/secrets', __FILE__)
```

3) And the addition to .gitignore

```
config/secrets.rb
```

Bonus) Add a config/secrets.rb.example template file which is not in .gitignore.

Comment: This way is great for production-configurable settings (mail credentials, oauth tokens, etc.)